# Minishift Start Failure: Error - Timed Out Waiting for the Condition

Tags: devops, openshift, minikube, manjaro, minishift

I'm encountering an issue while trying to start Minishift, and I would appreciate any guidance or insights to resolve it.

**Error Details:**

```
Starting Minishift FAIL, Error: timed out waiting for the condition #3584
```

**System Information:**

- Minishift version: `minishift v1.34.1+c2ff9cb`
- OS: 6.5.11-1-MANJARO
- Hypervisor: KVM

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Run: `minishift start --vm-driver=kvm`

**Expected Outcome:**
Minishift should start successfully.

**Actual Outcome:**
Minishift fails to start with a timeout error.

**Logs:**

```bash
$ minishift start --vm-driver=kvm                               

-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... SKIP
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'kvm' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if KVM driver is installed ... 
   Driver is available at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm ... 
   Checking driver binary is executable ... OK
-- Checking if Libvirt is installed ... OK
-- Checking if Libvirt default network is present ... OK
-- Checking if Libvirt default network is active ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Downloading OpenShift binary 'oc' version 'v3.11.0'
 53.89 MiB / 53.89 MiB [============================================] 100.00% 0s-- Downloading OpenShift v3.11.0 checksums ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'kvm' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    2 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 10 GB

   Downloading ISO 'https://github.com/minishift/minishift-centos-iso/releases/download/v1.15.0/minishift-centos7.iso'
 355.00 MiB / 355.00 MiB [==========================================] 100.00% 0s
-- Starting Minishift VM ............... OK
-- Checking for IP address ... OK
-- Checking for nameservers ... OK
-- Checking if external host is reachable from the Minishift VM ... 
   Pinging 8.8.8.8 ... OK
-- Checking HTTP connectivity from the VM ... 
   Retrieving http://minishift.io/index.html ... FAIL
   VM cannot connect to external URL with HTTP
-- Checking if persistent storage volume is mounted ... OK
-- Checking available disk space ... 1% used OK
-- Writing current configuration for static assignment of IP address ... WARN
   Importing 'openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0'  CACHE MISS
   Importing 'openshift/origin-docker-registry:v3.11.0'  CACHE MISS
   Importing 'openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v3.11.0'  CACHE MISS
-- OpenShift cluster will be configured with ...
   Version: v3.11.0
-- Pulling the OpenShift Container Image ......................................... OK
-- Copying oc binary from the OpenShift container image to VM ... OK
-- Starting OpenShift cluster .....................................................................................Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster. ssh command error:
command : /var/lib/minishift/bin/oc cluster up --routing-suffix 192.168.42.202.nip.io --base-dir /var/lib/minishift/base --image 'openshift/origin-${component}:v3.11.0' --public-hostname 192.168.42.202
err     : exit status 1
output  : Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
Pulling image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0
E1125 20:24:38.571416    4483 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/docker/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/docker/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0 anonymously
Image pull complete
Pulling image openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0
E1125 20:24:42.759502    4483 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/docker/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/docker/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0 anonymously
Pulled 5/6 layers, 84% complete
Pulled 5/6 layers, 94% complete
Pulled 6/6 layers, 100% complete
Extracting
Image pull complete
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Using public hostname IP 192.168.42.202 as the host IP
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 ...
I1125 20:25:49.765387    4483 config.go:40] Running "create-master-config"
I1125 20:25:51.139086    4483 config.go:46] Running "create-node-config"
I1125 20:25:51.572675    4483 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I1125 20:25:51.851812    4483 run_kubelet.go:49] Running "start-kubelet"
I1125 20:25:52.006643    4483 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
I1125 20:27:37.069894    4483 interface.go:26] Installing "kube-proxy" ...
I1125 20:27:37.076207    4483 interface.go:26] Installing "kube-dns" ...
I1125 20:27:37.076214    4483 interface.go:26] Installing "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" ...
I1125 20:27:37.076217    4483 interface.go:26] Installing "openshift-apiserver" ...
I1125 20:27:37.098725    4483 apply_template.go:81] Installing "kube-proxy"
I1125 20:27:37.100244    4483 apply_template.go:81] Installing "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator"
I1125 20:27:37.108935    4483 apply_template.go:81] Installing "kube-dns"
I1125 20:27:37.113706    4483 apply_template.go:81] Installing "openshift-apiserver"
I1125 20:27:39.742802    4483 interface.go:41] Finished installing "kube-proxy" "kube-dns" "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" "openshift-apiserver"
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

I've checked the Minishift and OpenShift versions, ensured the required dependencies are present, and attempted the start process with the KVM hypervisor. Despite these efforts, the timeout error persists.

Minishift should be started but not working